# Gcloud overriding region, zone and machine-type in a single command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm working my way through GCP ACE material, and when creating a compute instance you can do the following:

```
gcloud compute instance create --machine-type=f1-micro mylovelyVM
```

This is all good, but I want to know how to override region and zone in the same command, I know I can just do config set the region and zone but would be nice to know if it's possible in the one line command.

I have tried the following to no avail :

`gcloud compute instances create --machine-type=f1-micro mylovelyVM --region us-west2 --zone us-west2-b`

`gcloud compute instances create --region us-west2 --zone us-west2-b --machine-type=f1-micro mylovelyVM`

I have tried variations on this.

I have been using the -h and --help commands to try and work out at what point to specify the region, but so far no luck.

Error message is `--region (did you mean '--reservation'?)` for every iteration, which leads me to think its not expecting --region flag at that point.

Documentation states the flow should be `gcloud <global flags> <service/product> <group/area> <command> <flags> <parameters>`

In which case the command should be

```
gcloud compute --region us-west2 --zone us-west2-b instances create --machine-type=f1-micro mylovelyVM
```

Is there a limit on chaining overrides or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create instances in zones not regions. Regions comprise multiple zones and, while some other services *are* regional, (compute engine) instances must be placed in zones.

So, use only `--zone=..` and not `--region=...`

The documentation is good but `gcloud compute instances create` has many flags and so it can be confusing:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

Using Cloud Console, you can try permutations of the command and, at the bottom, there's an option to have Console show you the equivalent REST or Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) command. This is helpful.

IMO, it **is** good practice to specify e.g. `--zone`, `--project` and other flags on the command-line rather than use config. It's more typing but it's more explicit and can avoid errors that result from implicit (assumed) values from config.

Best wishes for your learning!

#### Update

```sh
gcloud compute instances create mylovelyvm \
--zone=us-west2-b \
--machine-type=f1-micro \
--project=${PROJECT}
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${PROJECT}/zones/us-west2-b/instances/mylovelyvm].
NAME        ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
mylovelyvm  us-west2-b  f1-micro                   10.168.0.2   35.236.23.189  RUNNING
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately using --zone=.. still gives the same issue, (just zone as the unrecognised flag). Totally agree with your sentiments, thanks and will keep at it!

Comment: `gcloud compute --zone us-west2-b instances create --machine-type=f1-micro mylovelyVM `  
 
Help says to use prefix zones, but that also doesn't work. Additionally, using `--zone=us-west2-b` is also unrecognized.

Comment: @Murchie85, try `gcloud compute instances create mylovelyvm --zone=us-west2-b --machine-type=f1-micro`

Comment: The command is fine but (!) to pursue your hypothesis, you should add `--project=....` (and your project ID). In my case: `gcloud compute instances create mylovelyvm \
--zone=us-west2-b --machine-type=f1-micro --project=${PROJECT}`. Comments aren't very useful here... updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks Daz,that is brilliant! I also managed to get it working independently by trial and error and more reading.  
`gcloud compute instances create my-lovelyVM --zone=us-west2-b --machine-type=f1-micro`

Answer (score 0):

Marking Daz's answer as correct, though I did find a way without specifying project :

`gcloud compute instances create my-lovelyVM --zone=us-west2-b --machine-type=f1-micro`